# Azure Spatial Anchor - how to get sufficient environment data?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, azure-spatial-anchors

I'm trying to build an AR **Android** application using **Unity 2019.4.19f1** and **Azure Spatial Anchor** in order to save the anchors to the cloud.

I'm using the **SpatialAnchorManager** class given in the [demo](https://github.com/Azure/azure-spatial-anchors-samples). Once the session is created and started, I Try saving a Prefab to the cloud with the following Method but the **CloudManager.SessionStatus.RecommendedForCreateProgress** never gets above 0.

```cs
protected virtual async Task SaveCurrentObjectAnchorToCloudAsync(GameObject spawnedObject)
    {
        CloudNativeAnchor cna = spawnedObject.GetComponent<CloudNativeAnchor>();

        // If the cloud portion of the anchor hasn't been created yet, create it
        if (cna.CloudAnchor == null) { cna.NativeToCloud(); }

        // Get the cloud portion of the anchor
        CloudSpatialAnchor cloudAnchor = cna.CloudAnchor;

        while (!CloudManager.IsReadyForCreate)
        {
            await Task.Delay(330);
            float createProgress = CloudManager.SessionStatus.RecommendedForCreateProgress;
            feedBack.text = $"Move your device to capture more environment data: {createProgress}";
        }
        bool success = false;

        feedBack.text = "Saving...";

        try
        {
            await CloudManager.CreateAnchorAsync(cloudAnchor);
            var currentCloudAnchor = cloudAnchor;
            success = currentCloudAnchor != null;

            if (success && !isErrorActive)
            {
                await OnSaveCloudAnchorSuccessfulAsync();
            }
            else
            {
                OnSaveCloudAnchorFailed(new Exception("Failed to save, but no exception was thrown."));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            OnSaveCloudAnchorFailed(ex);
        }
    }
```